# What is "multitasking diagram" for a sub-system

Tags: architecture, embedded

I'm trying to do my project of embedded system. The system contains several sub-systems. My Professor said that I should create/design "multitasking diagram" for a selected sub-system. I have to do it in SysML (like UML but for embedded system)
What is it? How should I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: That is not what SysML is - rather it is a to UML profile for whole systems rather than just software.

Answer (score 2):

The official OMG taxonomy of SysML diagrams is as follows:
[image: SysML Taxonomy]

As you can see there no "multitasking diagram", so it is not possible to determine what you are being asked to produce; you would have to ask your professor - that is rather what he is there for after all.

However aspects of *concurrency* can be represented in many ways in SysML/UML, such as the `par` fragment operator in sequence diagrams, fork in activity and state-machine diagrams, and orthogonal states.

In UML, a class or object can be represented as `<<active>>` by stereotype and in UML 2 is represented by two vertical bars on the left and right side of the box, however SysML does not specify class diagrams.

I would suggest that SysML is the wrong tool for a "multitasking diagram" since it is entirely a software concept and not a systems engineering issue.  Your understanding of SysML as "like UML but for embedded systems" is incorrect - it is a dialect of UML for *systems engineering* and modelling.  A *system* encompasses electronic, computing and mechanical elements.

A UML tasking diagram would be constructed from a class diagram that shows only model elements related to the concurrency model such as:

- Active objects
- Semaphore objects
- Message and data queues
- Constraints
- Tagged values

Example from [Bruce Powell-Douglass/Telelogic](http://archive.oredev.org/download/18.5bd7fa0510edb4a8ce4800019180/1385353960592/Bruce_Douglass_-_Workshop_Real-Time_UML.pdf):
[image: Task Diagram]

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. You're right about SysML, it's for system engineering.
The link you give is helpful. I'm having a check and will accept your answer if I can produce a diagram accepted by my Professor :)